# Can you iterate over the properties of an eloquent object?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, unit-of-work

If I have for example:

```
$project = new Project(); // Project is a class that extends Eloquent
$project->title;
$project->something;
```

Is it possible to iterate over those properties... something like this:

```
foreach( $project as $key => $value )
{
    echo $key;
}
```

I am trying to do this to achieve a unit of work for editing Eloquent models

Comment: `$project->toArray()`

Comment: Spot on, put it as the answer :)

Comment: Ok, done. Glad i could help

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the `toArray()` method:

```
foreach( $project->toArray() as $key => $value )
{
    echo $key;
}
```

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json

Answer (score 11):

You can also use `getAttributes()` method:

```
foreach ($project->getAttributes() as $k => $v) {
    echo $k.' '.$v."<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop through an Eloquent model object, you can try this way:

In your controller/component:

```
$results = Users::where(...)->paginate(10);
$items = collect($results->items();
```

In your blade view:

```
@foreach ($items->toArray() as $k => $v) {}
```